# Declared variables stack

Tags: c, debugging, variables, gdb, stack

I have 2 files name auth_overflow & auth_overflow2, the only difference is the sequence of the variable declaration. My question is, does declaration sequence affect their stack sequence according to FILO (first in last out)?

**auth_overflow**

```
bash-4.2$ gdb -q auth_overflow
Reading symbols from /home/reader/hacking/auth_overflow...done.
(gdb) list
5       int check_authetication (char *password) {
6               int auth_flag = 0;
7               char password_buffer[16];
8
9               strcpy(password_buffer, password);

(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804850d: file auth_overflow.c, line 9.
(gdb) run AAAAAAAAAAAA
Starting program: /home/reader/hacking/auth_overflow AAAAAAAAAAAA

Breakpoint 1, check_authetication (password=0xbffff7f3 'A' <repeats 12 times>) at auth_overflow.c:9
9               strcpy(password_buffer, password);
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff52c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff53c:     0x00000000
```

**auth_overflow2**

```
bash-4.2$ gdb -q auth_overflow2
Reading symbols from /home/reader/hacking/auth_overflow2...done.
(gdb) list
5       int check_authetication (char *password) {
6               char password_buffer[16];
7               int auth_flag = 0;
8
9               strcpy(password_buffer, password);

(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804850d: file auth_overflow2.c, line 9.
(gdb) run AAAAAAAAAAAA
Starting program: /home/reader/hacking/auth_overflow2 AAAAAAAAAAAA

Breakpoint 1, check_authetication (password=0xbffff7f2 'A' <repeats 12 times>) at auth_overflow2.c:9
9               strcpy(password_buffer, password);
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff52c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff53c:     0x00000000
```

Normal output:

```
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff52c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff53c:     0x00000000
```

Expected output after variable swapped:

```
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff53c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff52c:     0x00000000
```

I swapped between line 6 & 7 and I expect their corresponding addresses to be swapped too. Instead, their addresses remain the same despite the swap. Is there any explanation for this? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the compiler and the optimizer options.  Some compilers will reorder local variables on the stack in different orders depending on things like the size.

Comment: are you using a 64bit machine? if thats the case the stack behaves slightly different to a 32bit machine, variables are pushed into registers and then to the stack on 64bit machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the assembly output by @harper the compiler can freely reorder the stack of variables therefore in this case it's always char array before int variable. This makes the program vulnerable for stack-based buffer overflow.

In order to change the following:

```
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff52c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff53c:     0x00000000
```

Into expected output as below:

```
(gdb) x/x password_buffer
0xbffff53c:     0x08048330
(gdb) x/x &auth_flag
0xbffff52c:     0x00000000
```

We simply add a `-fstack-protector-all` argument during compilation and the result will be as expected. To be vice-versa, perhaps you can use `-O0` or `-fno-stack-protector`.

Thank you @harper and @tesseract for your contribution :-)

Comment: I think you are drawing conclusions that aren't necessarily true based on a very small sample size. Compilers are pretty much free to arrange local variables however they want. In fact, local variables might not be represented on the stack at all (using registers), or the same location can be used for multiple local variables if the compiler detects that the times when the variables are in active use do not overlap. The compiler could even use different memory locations at different points in the function. Finally, taking the address of the variable may change how the compiler treats it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yea I agreed that this conclusion isn't solid and it serves only as a temporary solution. In this case can you kindly show me the solution in order to obtain the expected output from modifying the gcc arguments other than the one I stated? I actually got this idea from the following file: [Stack Smashing Protector](http://bit.ly/1agVXIj)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the variable declaration is irrelevant since it's only a declaration.

When you define the variable as local variables (on the stack) the compiler can allocate any appropriate place on the stack, align the variables and "reorders" them. It's not really a reorder, since only the compiler chooses the order.

Example:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;

    return a + b;
}

int bar(void)
{
    int b;
    int a;

    return a + b;
}
```

will be compiled by the GCC to this assembler code:
[gcc -S --verbose-asm foo.c]

```
        .text
        .align  2
        .global foo
        .type   foo, %function
foo:
        @ Function supports interworking.
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
        @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!  @,
        add     fp, sp, #0      @,,
        sub     sp, sp, #12     @,,
        ldr     r2, [fp, #-8]   @ tmp136, a
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-12]  @ tmp137, b
        rsb     r3, r3, r2      @ D.4069, tmp137, tmp136
        mov     r0, r3  @, <retval>
        add     sp, fp, #0      @,,
        ldmfd   sp!, {fp}
        bx      lr
        .size   foo, .-foo
        .align  2
        .global bar
        .type   bar, %function
bar:
        @ Function supports interworking.
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
        @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!  @,
        add     fp, sp, #0      @,,
        sub     sp, sp, #12     @,,
        ldr     r2, [fp, #-8]   @ tmp136, a
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-12]  @ tmp137, b
        rsb     r3, r3, r2      @ D.4067, tmp137, tmp136
        mov     r0, r3  @, <retval>
        add     sp, fp, #0      @,,
        ldmfd   sp!, {fp}
        bx      lr
        .size   bar, .-bar
```

As you can see the variable a is always at the same address `[fp-8]`. My observation for GCC is that the variables are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: If what you told is correct then I'm afraid the book I'm reading is leading me to a wrong direction. Simply because the book mentioned about the swap of memory location after swapping the variables. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: Most of the answer ins't written by me but the compiler. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I'll keep looking for an answer as the result is vary depend on machine type :-)

Comment: "My observation for GCC is that the variables are sorted alphabetically."
That is probably true for same size variables, but I believe size is the first sorting dimension. In fact, I have a `char test_array [16]` and a `int test_int` and, no matter how I declare them, the int one is always above the array in the stack (the distance between them is always 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

on a 32bit machine the order of declaration affects where its placed in memory, not sure exactly how a 64bit machine handles it, but from memory it pushed variables into registers and then to the stack.

lets assume u use a 32bit machine in that case the memory locations must be swapped, are you sure you compiled your code after swapping?.

auth_overflow seems correct,
auth_overflow2 should give the expected output in your question, not sure why this may be. the only reason I can think of is try recompile the code.

Comment: Yea, I've attached the 'list' command output to show that I'd recompiled the code. I agreed with the swap in memory address after swapping their declaration. However it just doesn't work.

Comment: is it a 64 bit computer?

Comment: I just ran both overflow and overflow 2 on my computer made a very simple program with 2 variables and then swapped them, and they are as expected, the memory locations are swapped for auth_overflow2. I am using my 64bit mac so there seems to be no problem with  64 or 32bit OS.some info about your computer might be useful since most of the time these things depends on the type of compiler and machine architecture.

Comment: `bash-4.2$ uname -a`

Linux darkstar 3.10.17 #2 Wed Oct 23 17:46:52 CDT 2013 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9550  @ 2.83GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

Comment: `bash-4.2$ gcc --version`
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2

Comment: I'm running a 32-bit Slackware 14.1 on a 64-bit supported CPU (Intel C2Q  Q9550). May I know which distro are you running? Thanks.

Comment: I am using a Mac, Osx Mavericks..think this has mostly to do with your compiler. but its strange, even I thought the variables are pushed on to the stack in the order you declare them, but that does not seem to be the case.  @harpers explanation is valid and correct

Comment: Would you mind to show me the output of `gcc --version` please? Thank you.

Comment: my mac users apple LLVM compiler version 5.0, I tried this on my linux computer with gcc, and I get the same thing you get, the addresses do not get switched but on my MAC they get switched. surprising I was not aware of this.gcc --version is 4.8.2 I would not worry about this too much. best way to do buffer overflows is to change the return address to point to some code in memory

Comment: Yea I agreed with the ret address buffer overflow but I just want to experiment with different kind of attacks. However, I just found a temporary solution for this situation & I've attached it as an answer for this question.